# Error using custom class on the live server for Laravel 5

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5

Using Laravel 5.2, I created a folder on my local machine inside of the app directory. The name of the folder is mailers. Inside of that folder are 2 classes.

I updated my composer.json file like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/foo"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Acme\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

After running composer update and composer dump-autoload, everything works fine on the local machine. However, after uploading the code to the live server, I run composer dump-autoload and receive the following error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                           
Could not scan for classes inside "app/foo" which does not appear to be a file
nor a folder
```

How can I get my custom class recognized on the live server? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Cheers :)

Comment: could you post your complete composer.json?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but I fixed the issue. When I uploaded the app, the foo folder was made uppercase and it's lowercase in the composer.json file. So changing foo to Foo in composer.json resolved the issue.